# Using Stellar for Proof of Existence

Tags: transactions, memo

I know Stellar is designed for transfering funds and holding tokens, but I thought about using it for proof of existence. Stellars transaction fees are much cheaper than Ethereum and transactions are much faster. Could Stellar be used for PoE?

I would transfer lumen from my account to the same account (or another one I own) in a transaction and use the PoE SHA256 in the memo field, would this work?

When proofing existence, can I search all memo fields in Stellar for a SHA256?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It definitely works, I did a PoC years ago doing just that.

Search is going to be the complicated part, since Horizon doesn't really give you any easy way to filter out transactions based on their memo, unless you host a server yourself and talk directly to the database.

Comment: So I would neet ot keep a record of these transactions and if someone wants the proof point to the transaction on the stellar blockchain?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the above answer it will work definitely, but you need to keep a stellar node to query the things effectively. Or else what i did was i stored the Txn hashes in my database and when some one ask i will send the hashes to them to verify.